# Can you only have stride size 1 with resize convolutions?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

I read this article about using "resize convolutions" rather than the "deconvolution" (i.e. transposed convolution) method for generating images with neural networks. It's clear how this works with a stride size of 1, but how would you implement it for a stride size >1?

Here is how I've implemented this in TensorFlow. Note: This is the second "deconvolution" layer in the decoder part of an autoencoder network.

```
h_d_upsample2 = tf.image.resize_images(images=h_d_conv3,
                                       size=(int(self.c2_size), int(self.c2_size)),
                                       method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
h_d_conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=h_d_upsample2,
                             filters=FLAGS.C2,
                             kernel_size=(FLAGS.c2_kernel, FLAGS.c2_kernel),
                             padding='same',
                             activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

Comment: It's too bad these answers missed the point of the question. I'd also like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing images really not a viable option for intermediate layers of network. you may try `conv2d_transpose`

> how would you implement it for a stride size >1?

```
# best practice is to use the transposed_conv2d function, this function works with stride >1 . 
# output_shape_width_height = stride * input_shape_width_height
# input_shape = [32, 32, 48], output_shape = [64, 64, 128]
stride = 2
filter_size_w =filter_size_h= 2 
shape = [filter_size_w, filter_size_h, output_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]]
w = tf.get_variable(
    name='W',
    shape=shape,
    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scalling_initializer(),
    trainable=trainable)

output = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(
        input, w, output_shape=output_shape, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1])
```